# Django: disable APPEND_SLASH for certain URLs

Tags: django

I have a view that protects certain sensitive files from public download, using nginx' `X-Accel-Redirect` header. My URL looks like this:

```
url(r'^dl/f/(?P<pk>\d+)/(?P<filename>[^/]+)$', 'file_download.views.download', name='download-filename'),
```

`pk` is the primary key of the file object in the database, `filename` is the file name, which matches anything but the forward slash. It's mainly there so that the browser knows the file name in case the user wants to save it. Note that there is no terminal slash.

When I open a matching URL in the browser, Django nevertheless redirects it to the same URL with a slash appended. The file is displayed in the browser (it's a PDF), but if I want to save it, the browser suggests a generic "download.pdf" instead of the file name.

I don't want to disable `APPEND_SLASH` for the general case, but can I somehow get around it for this single case?

/edit: unfortunately, I can't use the `Content-Disposition: attachment` header, because all other files are served without that header as well, and consistent behavior for both protected and unprotected files is a requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know where/if it's in the docs, but I believe that putting an extension into the URL will prevent this behavior, so instead of `some-filename/`, use `some-filename.pdf` (and alter the urlpattern accordingly, of course).

However, I'm not entirely sure about that. Really, your primary problem seems to be that the download's filename is not set properly, and that can be fixed without messing with the URLs one way or another. Just store the response instead of returning it immediately, and then alter the `Content-Disposition` header:

```
response = HttpResponse(mimetype='application/pdf')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=somefilename.pdf'
```

**UPDATE**

Concerning the two points in your comment:

1. The urlpattern can accept a wildcard extension `\.\w{3,4}`.
2. 'attachment' is what forces a download. 'inline' can be used to make the file load in the browser. The filename can be asserted either way.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I can't use the `Content-Disposition` header, because non-protected files are also served without it, and the client (understandably) wants consistent behavior.

Also, the "extension-in-url-pattern" doesn't really work for me as well, because the view not only servers PDFs, but all kind of files.

Comment: Huh? It's just a header that signals the client (the browser) to download the file. Are you saying that you don't want it to force a download, but rather display in the browser?

Comment: Yes. Without the header, browsers that support the file type open it "inline" instead of downloading it, e.g. PDFs in Chrome. I want to maintain that behavior. Setting the `Content-Disposition` to `attachment` presents the user with the download dialog no matter if the browser could display the file natively or not.

Comment: See update. Just use `'inline; filename=somefilename.pdf'`. The file will load in the browser window, but if they attempt to save it, the filename you set will be used. Problem solved.